# Subtracting datetime value from previous row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, shift, subtraction

I have a dataframe with two columns: **Category** and **Datetime**

I want to create a new column that shows the difference between the Datetime of the current row vs the previous row, **restarting at each category**.

What I have:

```
Category    Datetime
A           2018-02-01 01:51:04
A           2018-02-01 02:04:04
B           2018-02-01 02:28:34 
B           2018-02-01 02:41:34
B           2018-02-01 02:45:34
```

What I want:

```
Category    Datetime               Difference
A           2018-02-01 01:51:04    NaT
A           2018-02-01 02:04:04    00:13:00
B           2018-02-01 02:28:34    NaT
B           2018-02-01 02:41:34    00:13:00
B           2018-02-01 02:45:34    00:04:00
```

---

EDIT:

@sacul I tried your solution of doing `df['Difference'] = list(by_group.apply(lambda x: x['Datetime']-x['Datetime'].shift()))` but it's giving me weird results...here's the actual data I'm working with:

```
Category    Datetime        Difference
A           2/1/18 1:51     NaT
A           2/1/18 2:04     1 days 02:52:00
B           2/1/18 2:28     NaT
C           2/1/18 2:41     NaT
D           2/1/18 6:31     0 days 00:10:30
E           2/1/18 8:26     3 days 23:19:30
F           2/1/18 10:03    0 days 00:21:00
G           2/1/18 11:11    NaT
G           2/1/18 11:11    NaT
G           2/1/18 11:11    0 days 00:00:02
G           2/1/18 11:11    0 days 00:02:30
H           2/1/18 11:12    0 days 00:00:02
H           2/1/18 11:22    0 days 00:02:28
I           2/1/18 15:26    0 days 00:00:02
I           2/1/18 16:01    0 days 00:08:26
I           2/1/18 17:26    0 days 00:00:01
J           2/1/18 17:42    0 days 00:01:31
J           2/1/18 17:42    NaT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

alternative solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)


df['Difference'] = np.where(df.Category == df.Category.shift(), df.DateTime - df.DateTime.shift(), np.nan)
```

note: this only works if your data is presorted

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df`:

```
# In case Datetime is not a Datetime object yet (skip if it is):
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)

by_group = df.groupby(df.Category)

df['Difference'] = list(by_group.apply(lambda x: x['Datetime']-x['Datetime'].shift()))

>>> df
  Category            Datetime Difference
0        A 2018-02-01 01:51:04        NaT
1        A 2018-02-01 02:04:04   00:13:00
2        B 2018-02-01 02:28:34        NaT
3        B 2018-02-01 02:41:34   00:13:00
4        B 2018-02-01 02:45:34   00:04:00
```

This groups it by category, and then subtracts the datetime object in each row from the row below in each group.

EDIT:

This seems to work with your new data as well, when starting with a `Datetime` column of *strings* in the form `2/1/18 1:51`, and modifying that via `pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)`:

```
>>> df1
   Category            Datetime Difference
0         A 2018-02-01 01:51:00        NaT
1         A 2018-02-01 02:04:00   00:13:00
2         B 2018-02-01 02:28:00        NaT
3         C 2018-02-01 02:41:00        NaT
4         D 2018-02-01 06:31:00        NaT
5         E 2018-02-01 08:26:00        NaT
6         F 2018-02-01 10:03:00        NaT
7         G 2018-02-01 11:11:00        NaT
8         G 2018-02-01 11:11:00   00:00:00
9         G 2018-02-01 11:11:00   00:00:00
10        G 2018-02-01 11:11:00   00:00:00
11        H 2018-02-01 11:12:00        NaT
12        H 2018-02-01 11:22:00   00:10:00
13        I 2018-02-01 15:26:00        NaT
14        I 2018-02-01 16:01:00   00:35:00
15        I 2018-02-01 17:26:00   01:25:00
16        J 2018-02-01 17:42:00        NaT
17        J 2018-02-01 17:42:00   00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi @sacul! I tried your solution, please see my edit above. `df.Datetime` is in datetime format (<M8[ns]). Also, `df['Datetime'] - df['Datetime'].shift()` gives me what I am looking for (except it doesn't restart for each category), so I'm guessing the problem lies in figuring out how to use **groupby** properly in this situation.

Comment: That's strange, it seems to work for me; I'm updating my answer with your new data:

Comment: I had to reprocess your data in order to get it into a dataframe, what I ended up with was a column named `Datetime` with *strings* in the form `2/1/18 1:51`, then called `pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)` on that column, went through the `groupby` process, and I got the results posted. Try changing your 'Datetime' column to strings, then doing as I posted. You can use `df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].to_string()`

Comment: I see, it's something with my datetime format (this data was exported from Splunk). When I did `df['Datetime'].to_string()` and then `pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])`, I got **ValueError: Unknown string format**. Apparently, the `to_string` command turned it into something super weird (it's long so I'll paste it in another comment). Going to manually reformat df.Datetime into a string and give your solution a try.

Comment: '41     2018-02-01 01:51:04\n72     2018-02-01 02:04:04\n73     2018-02-01 02:28:34\n74     2018-02-01 02:41:34\n82     2018-02-01 06:31:04\n71     2018-02-01 08:26:04\n209    2018-02-01 10:03:04\n203    2018-02-01 11:11:04\n204    2018-02-01 11:11:04\n205    2018-02-01 11:11:05\n206    2018-02-01 11:11:06\n207    2018-02-01 11:12:04\n208    2018-02-01 11:22:34\n202    2018-02-01 15:26:04\n201    2018-02-01 16:01:04\n58     2018-02-01 17:26:04\n59     2018-02-01 17:42:04\n60     2018-02-01 17:42:05\n62     2018-02-01 17:42:34\n61     2018-02-01 17:42:34\n63     2018-02-01 17:50:04\n64     ...

Comment: You can try changing it with `df.Datetime = df.Datetime.astype('str')`, it actually makes more sense than the `.to_string()` method (sorry, I should have tested that before my last comment!)

Comment: So weird, but still didn't work (getting those weird "0 days" results). However, @Usernamenotfound's solution worked like a charm - thanks guys!!